# Calculating modulo with only the four basic operations?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I'm wondering if a formula could be written that has the same results of modulo, only using add/subtract/divide/multiply (or exponentiation). NO USE OF ROUNDING. I swear I've seen something like this before, but I've looked everywhere and I can't find it.

Comment: $\left(x^2\right)^{1/2}$?

Answer (score 0):

For mod 2, notice that $(-1)^n$ is $1$ if $n$ is even and $-1$ if $n$ is odd, so

$$\frac{1-(-1)^n}{2}$$

Gives the value of $n$ modulo 2.

By replacing $-1$ with a $k$th root of unity, a similar trick should give a formula for taking modulo $k$

Answer (score 0):

As a software engineer, I would do for the recursive approach for calculating $a \mod n$ (taking into account the fact that both numbers are positive):

(if $a < n$) : $ a \mod n = a$
(if $a \ge n$) : $ a \mod n = (a - n) \mod n$

Answer (score 0):

There is a similar trick for $3$ by using the three roots of unity, $1,\omega, \omega^2$. If we rotate these by $\frac{3\pi}{2}$, the real parts align to $0, \cos(\frac{\pi}{6}), \cos(\frac{5\pi}{6})$, i.e. $0,\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2},-\frac{\sqrt3}{2}$.

So,

$$\frac{2\cos(\frac{3\pi}{2}+\frac{2n\pi}{3})}{\sqrt{3}}= \frac{2\cos(\frac{\pi(9+4n)}{6})}{\sqrt{3}}\equiv n \pmod 3$$